# What is metadata programming to Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, metaprogramming, spring-aop

What is metadata in spring. What is metadata programming to Spring. How Spring’s metadata support to add annotations to our source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Metadata is the data that describes your spring beans and their methods. Metadata can be added in multiple ways:

- xml - `<bean>`
- annotations (`@Service`, `@Component`, `@Lazy`, `@Async`, etc.)
- javaconfig - again annotations, but meant to allow more flexibility - `@Configuration`, `@Bean`.

I don't know what "metadata programming" is meant to mean, but it's likely the use of the above annotations and xml.

Comment: If one describe the beans with both xml and javaconfig on a bean, which configuration will be chosen and why?

Comment: That's a tougher question. There isn't a universal recipe and it's a metter of preference. I have some perslonal rules, but they aren't accepted practice

Answer (score 2):

Metadata is data about data in the most general sense of the term.  What metadata means for Spring is the data that describes your object models and beans to the Spring container or Spring related libraries.  Metadata isn't limited to just Spring.  The use of Annotations or XML in Java has always been about metadata.  Essentially it gives the user of some library or framework the ability to specify how they want their objects to behave in the framework.

Metadata programming is just as nebulous a term as Metadata.  There are two ends of the metadata side. The user who places metadata descriptions in configuration files, or adds annotations to their code, and the author of the code that interprets those configurations to perform some algorithm.  Metadata programming is simply writing algorithms that leverage metadata in some way to control how the algorithm behaves.

Why do we use metadata instead of coding it?  Because it enables us to write higher level software that doesn't require as much skill to configure or write, and enables more code reuse than if we tried to do it with code.  The user of the metadata isn't really programming in the truest sense of the word.  They are configuring algorithms.

Comment: Doesn't that confuse a programmer? Where should he look for a bean config, should he look at the code or the config files, It just creates more confusion, doesn't it?

Comment: No more than having a web.xml in your program which we've done for 15 years. We've been doing metadata programming for a very long time, and its grown over time because its useful and reduces the size of the code we write. And you could even argue longer than that if you wanted to include things like HTML, SGML, resource files, ui layout, etc. Spring Bean config file names are mostly standardized, and so anyone who knows Spring knows where to find that file. Spring bean configs just define the objects and their dependencies. After that what it does in response to input is your code.